# Is the fact that scipy.fft links to numpy.fft.fftpack.fft documented anywhere?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I couldn't find any official documentation of the fact that `scipy.fft` actually is a link to `numpy.fft.fftpack.fft`. Here is an iPython session showing the link:

```
In [1]: import scipy

In [2]: import numpy

In [3]: scipy.__version__
Out[3]: '0.19.0'

In [4]: numpy.__version__
Out[4]: '1.12.1'

In [5]: scipy.fft
Out[5]: <function numpy.fft.fftpack.fft>
```

The only mentions I could find of a `scipy.fft` submodule were [this discussion on numpy-discussion](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/FFTS-for-numpy-s-FFTs-was-Re-Choosing-between-NumPy-and-SciPy-functions-td38997.html) and [this discussion on SciPy's Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2487#issuecomment-255562820), both of which seem to hint at the fact that no such submodule actually existed at the time.

Comment: Why is this of interest for you? Isn't that an implementation detail that only needs to be documented in the source code?

Comment: There's plenty of stuff like this all over the place. Heck, I don't think the `scipy.fft` name is documented at all.

Comment: This is an unfortunate quirk of the `scipy` namespace.  It contains *all* of the numpy names (e.g. `scipy.array`, `scipy.linspace`, etc.).  The use of these names is discouraged; it is clearer to use the numpy namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy):

> #### Guidelines for importing functions from Scipy
>
> The scipy namespace itself only contains functions imported from numpy. These functions still exist for backwards compatibility, but should be imported from numpy directly.
>
> [...]

Comment: FYI (where "Y" is "y'all's", not just MSeifert's): One thing in the top-level `scipy` namespace that is useful is `scipy.__version__`.

Answer (score 1):

The `scipy.__init__.py` file has:

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand, randn
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from numpy.lib.scimath import *

__all__ += _num.__all__
__all__ += ['randn', 'rand', 'fft', 'ifft']
```